# Can't create custom arrayadapter with appcompat elements inside of it

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-appcompat

I have made an adapter which extends `ArrayAdapter` to create a list of custom items. The items have a drawable, a textview, and then finally an `AppCompatCheckBox`.

Unfortunately the `AppCompatCheckBox` compontents just don't get rendered. When I just change `AppCompatCheckBox` to `CheckBox` it works out just fine. I have added an `AppCompatCheckBox` to another section of my activity and it works just fine, its only when it is in the adapter that it is a problem.

Code samples below:

CustomItem:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class PackageListItem {

    private Boolean enabledState;
    private String packageName;
    private Drawable packageIcon;

    public PackageListItem(Boolean enabledState, String packageName, Drawable packageIcon){
        this.enabledState = enabledState;
        this.packageName = packageName;
        this.packageIcon = packageIcon;
    }

    public boolean getPackageEnabled(){
        return enabledState;
    }

    public Drawable getPackageIcon(){
        return packageIcon;
    }

    public String getPackageName(){
        return packageName;
    }

    public void setPackageEnabled(Boolean enabledState){
        this.enabledState = enabledState;
    }

    public void setPackageIcon(Drawable packageIcon){
        this.packageIcon = packageIcon;
    }

    public void setPackageName(String packageName){
        this.packageName = packageName;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class PackageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PackageListItem> {


    public PackageListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PackageListItem> packages){
        super(context, 0, packages);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        PackageListItem packageItem = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.package_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvPackageName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packageName);
        ImageView ivPackageIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packageIcon);
        CheckBox sPackageSwitch = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.packageEnabled);

        tvPackageName.setText(packageItem.getPackageName());
        ivPackageIcon.setImageDrawable(packageItem.getPackageIcon());
        sPackageSwitch.setChecked(packageItem.getPackageEnabled());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Custom Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/packageIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/packageName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/AppTheme.ListTitle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/packageEnabled"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Me initializing the list:

```
 private void initPackagesList(){
        ArrayList<PackageListItem> arrayListOfPackages = new ArrayList<>();

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> apps = pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER), 0);

        for(ResolveInfo apInfo : apps){
            String packageName = apInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
            Drawable packageIcon = apInfo.loadIcon(pm);
            boolean packageState = myPreferences.getBoolean(packageName, false);

            Log.d("MainActivity","" + packageName);

            PackageListItem item = new PackageListItem(packageState, packageName, packageIcon);

            arrayListOfPackages.add(item);
        }

        PackageListAdapter adapter = new PackageListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayListOfPackages);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.packages_listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The results:

[image: The checkboxes aren't there for some reason]

Comment: Are you sure that checkboxes are not rendering? Space is occupied, so element exist. Maybe it is white? Did you try with different background color?

Comment: About `AppCompatCheckbox` from documentation - *This will automatically be used when you use `CheckBox` in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.*. Adapter is not custom view (component).

Comment: I know they aren't rendering because I can't interact with them and he's they aren't white either.

Also Damian, I am creating a custom view component. It's an adapter comprised of custom view. Plus if I don't use the appcompat checkbox then they will be styled like ice cream sandwich checkboxes on older devices which is what I want to avoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies with the way you're initializing your adapter.

To fix your issue, replace `new PackageListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),arrayListOfPackages);` with `new PackageListAdapter(this,arrayListOfPackages);`. (or `getActivity()` if inside a fragment).

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the AppCompat library relies on [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) to style most views. Using `getApplicationContext()` passes, well, the base application context to your ListView adapter and thus bypasses the AppCompat [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html). Passing `this` or `getActivity()` passes the top [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) context that can tell LayoutInflaters to apply additional styling. Without it, your adapter's LayoutInflater uses default styling.

Of course, your activity should also extend [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) but I take it you already know that.